# Set <object>'s contentDocument from another DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I need to insert a DOM which is a complete SVG document into an `<object>` element. SO here's my code:

```
var svgDom   = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(streamedFile,'image/svg+xml');
var pagePics = document.querySelectorAll('#currentFiles figure object');

for (var i=0; i<pagePics.length; i++){
    pagePics[i].contentDocument = svgDom.document;
}
```

But this doesn't work. DOM inspector doesn't show `<object>`'s contentDocument property after this code has run.

It's possible to use jQuery if this makes things easier. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentDocument` is a read-only attribute. You can't move `Document`​s from one context to another.

Usually you'd have to `importNode` content from one document into another. However that's of little use if you've got different document types like SVG and HTML.

For loading SVG from a string string into an iframe or object, I'd think you'd have no choice but to create the element with a `data:` URL, eg. `<object data="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E...">`.

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to create a new `object` element with the DOM i have and replace the old one? 
And if it's impossible, won't it be too much load to serialize DOM, url_escape it and then unescape the escaped string?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to create an `object` dynamically. Of course neither `data:` URLs nor `querySelectorAll` will work on IE6-7, but then if we're talking SVG I guess we're not talking about IE...

Comment: But can we assign the DOM to a dynamically created `object`? I guess no, for if it's read-only attribute it should not matter if the object in the DOM already or not.

But what about the performace? Or since i have no options need not bother about it?

I'm making an Opera svg viewer widget, so IE is not a question. It's like coding paradise I should say :)!

Comment: No, you'd assign the `encodeURIComponent`-ed string in a `data:` URL to the `data` property of the new or existing `object`.

Comment: How would you style or get elements by IDs in the SVG then? data: URIs can't use IDs.

Comment: @Elijah: I'm not sure I see the problem you're referring to. You can certainly call `object.contentDocument.getElementById()` et al to interact with an SVG DOM inside an `<object>` element loaded from a `data:` URL.

Comment: I've found that data URI method is extremely resource-expensive, especially when a lot of objects need to be processed this way.

Comment: Will importNode work in an xhtml documet with svg and xhtml namespaces?